# Checking for outliers in a glmer (lme4 package) with 3 random factors

Tags: r, outliers, lme4-nlme, cooks-distance

I have a question relating to the checking for outliers and / or influential points in my dataset using a `glmer` model with 3 random variables. I'm investigating the detection rate (`SumDetections`) of receivers over increasing distance (`sc.c.distance`), and the effect of environmental influences on this (`depth`, `temperature` and `wind`) and how this differs between different transmitters used, controlling for random effects of `receiver ID`, `replicate` and `area`. I found that the `influence.ME` might be of help, so I checked it out.

In the manual I read that this package is only able to delete levels of 1 single grouping factor or 1 data point per time over the whole data set. Unless I read the package info incorrectly, this package cannot do what I'm looking for. I'm looking for a way to check for outliers nested within 4 grouping layers.

How my data is organized is as follows: First my data discerns between `Areas`. Within areas, multiple `replicates` were done. Each replicate consisted of 5 `distances` at which the detection rate was tested. For each distance, 20 `receivers` were tested.

My model looks like this:

```
m <- lmer(SumDetections ~ tm + sc.c.distance + tm:sc.c.distance + c.tm.depth + 
             c.receiver.depth + c.temp + c.wind + (1|replicate) + (1|SUR.ID) + (1|Area), 
             data = df3, family = poisson)
```

My questions are:

- Is it possible to check for outliers of which the data is nested within 3 layers with use of influence.me?
- If so, how should I specify the command to get what I'm looking for, and how should I interpret the returned data by the Cook's distance or dfbetas?
- If not, is there another package that allows me to check for outliers?

Comment: Anyone? I posted in the lme4 mailing list as well, but I still haven't got a solution to my problem.
THanks

Comment: Which function in influence.ME are you trying to use?  If I remember correctly 1 of the 3 has limits on the number of random effects it can handle, while the other 2 are more flexible. Bolker has a glmm walk through with code for diagnostic functions that do basic flagging of outliers http://rpubs.com/bbolker/glmmchapter  You could use these to eyeball outliers and remove them by hand.  I don't know the theory behind how influence.ME works but you could probably get an approximate solution by looping over your dataset and calculating influence by hand.

Answer (score 1):

try the romr.fnc in the LMERConvenienceFunctions to remove outliers

```
df3.trimmed = romr.fnc(m, df3, trim = 2.5)
df3.trimmed = df3.trimmed$data
```

update initial model on trimmed data

```
mB = update(m1)
```

Comment: I looked at the package, and found that this cannot be used for GLMMs. Sorry if I didn't specify this clearly, but i'm trying to fit a GLMM with a poisson distribution.